# Is there an R function for subtracting values in a variable by group based on specified conditions?

Tags: r, function, dplyr, grouping

I have a df that takes this general form:

```r
ID    votes
1      65
1      85
2      100
2      20
2      95
3      50
3      60
```

I want to create a new df that takes the two highest values in votes for each ID and shows their difference. The new df should look like this:

```r
ID    margin
1      20
2      5
3      10
```

Is there a way to use dplyr for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22589851/build-difference-between-groups-with-dplyr-in-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option would be to be `arrange` by 'ID', 'votes' (either in `desc`ending or ascending), grouped by 'ID' and get the `diff` of the first two 'votes'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    arrange(ID, desc(votes)) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    summarise(margin = abs(diff(votes[1:2])))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#     ID margin
#  <int>  <int>
#1     1     20
#2     2      5
#3     3     10
```

---

Or another option is

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(margin = max(votes) - max(votes[-which.max(votes)]))
```

---

Or with `slice` and `diff`

```
df1 %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   slice(row_number(votes)[1:2]) %>% 
   summarise(margin = diff(votes))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), votes = c(65L, 
85L, 100L, 20L, 95L, 50L, 60L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```